# Installing Light Switch

Tags: switch, motion-sensor

I'm trying to connect a new light switch but can't seem to figure out what connects with what.  Can someone please help me?  Thank you!

[image: Box]

[image: Switch]

Comment: Thank you that worked!  The bare wire is ground as well.  I connected the green and bare wire to the box itself.  The 2 black wires I connected like they were previously.  I left the white wires alone.

Comment: I'm going to add to an answer for you to accept and uptick in case it helps others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never connected a motion switch before but it looks like the two whites neutrals in the wall box stay together, and then just twist one of the two blacks coming out the wall box each and individually with one of the blacks coming off the switch (just pick one from wall to twist with wire nut with one on the switch, and then do the other blacks). The green and the other small wire are ground wires so those will go from a newly connected pigtail to the metal box, and follow instructions from the **Important Grounding Note** section below for correctly connecting the grounds.

**Important Grounding Note:** *You should use pigtails to connect the two grounding conductors to the circuit grounding conductors, and the box. Putting them all under the same screw, is not the proper way to do it.*

Comment: Screw terminals are not designed for multiple conductors. The OP should use pigtails to connect the two grounding conductors to the circuit grounding conductors, and the box. Putting them all under the same screw, is not the proper way to do it.